# Spring Boot: read from yaml using @ConfigurationProperties not working with @Data

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans, spring-kafka

I am trying to retrieve value from application.yml. The final line below is showing kafkaConfig as null, and cannot read. How do I setup the Kafka Config and code properly, to read from the json file? We are using @Data instead of getters/setters.

**KafkaConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("kafka")
@Data
public class KafkaConfig {
    private String topic;
    private String event;
}
```

**Application.yml**

```
kafka:
  topic: "testTopic"
  event: "testEvent"
```

**KafkaProducerBeans.java**

```
@Component
public class KafkaProducerBeans {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConfig kafkaConfig;

    public KafkaProducerBeans(KafkaConfig kafkaConfig) {
        this.kafkaConfig = kafkaConfig;
    }

    @Bean(name = "kafkaTestClient")
    public String getData() {
        return kafkaConfig.getTopic();  // final line is creating null for kafka Config
    }
```

Resource: https://codingnconcepts.com/spring-boot/spring-configuration-properties-using-yml/

Comment: Make sure on your main boostrapping class you are using `@SpringBootApplication` it has `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which helps to enable your configuration automatically else you will need to use `@EnableConfigurationProperties` to enable it explictly.

Comment: Rather than define those properties, you should read the docs on `spring-kafka` config - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.messaging.kafka

Comment: yeah @OneCricketeer our company is using a Kafka wrapper, so they want me to use it this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the recommended way of binding properties to pojos is to use the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation like so:

**KafkaConfig.java**

```
@ConfigurationProperties("kafka")
@Data
public class KafkaConfig {
    private String topic;
    private String event;
}
```

**KafkaProducerBeans.java**

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KafkaConfig.class)
public class KafkaProducerBeans {

    private final KafkaConfig kafkaConfig;

    @Autowired
    public KafkaProducerBeans(KafkaConfig kafkaConfig) {
        this.kafkaConfig = kafkaConfig;
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Refer to the official Spring Documentation for further details:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.java-bean-binding
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.enabling-annotated-types

Answer (score 2):

Add one more annotation `@EnableConfigurationProperties` on the class `KafkaConfig`

**KafkaConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties    // new added annotation
@ConfigurationProperties("kafka")
@Data
public class KafkaConfig {
    private String topic;
    private String event;
}
```

Comment: `@EnableConfigurationProperties` not needed to mentioned Spring Boot documentation says, every project automatically includes `@EnableConfigurationProperties.` Therefore, `@ConfiguratonProperties` support is implicitly turned on in every Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 1):

@ComponentScan(basePackages ="PATH" )

PATH: the package path you want it to look for

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages ="PATH" )
@Configuration
@Import(value = {
    KafkaProducerBeans.class
})
public class AppConfig{

}
```

Comment: do this in the App.config class. Import KafkaConfig class into App.config class.